# Hosting more than 25 WCF services in Azure

Tags: wcf, azure, soa

We're running into Azure's limit of 25 internal endpoints with our WCF services. In keeping with SOA principles, our WCF services are fairly small, generally one per "noun" in our system. We are defining one Azure InternalEndpoint per service contract. We now want to add our 26th WCF service but can't because of the limit of 25 endpoints. We really don't want to arbitrarily start combining service contracts simply because of this Azure limitation.

Question: is there a better way to host lots of WCF services that doesn't require one endpoint per service contract?

Here's an example csdef file snippet:

```
<ServiceDefinition name="MyDeployment" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition">
  <WorkerRole name="MyWorkerRole" vmsize="Small">
    <Endpoints>
      <InternalEndpoint protocol="tcp" name="IUserService" />
      <InternalEndpoint protocol="tcp" name="IArticleService" />
      <InternalEndpoint protocol="tcp" name="IDocumentService" />
      <InternalEndpoint protocol="tcp" name="ICommentingService" />
      <InternalEndpoint protocol="tcp" name="ILocationService" />
      <InternalEndpoint protocol="tcp" name="IAuthorizationService" />
      <InternalEndpoint protocol="tcp" name="IAuthenticationService" />
      <InternalEndpoint protocol="tcp" name="ILoggingService" />
      <InternalEndpoint protocol="tcp" name="IService09" />
      <InternalEndpoint protocol="tcp" name="IService10" />
      <!-- and so on -->
      <InternalEndpoint protocol="tcp" name="IService24" />
      <InternalEndpoint protocol="tcp" name="IService25" />
      <InternalEndpoint protocol="tcp" name="IServiceWeWantToAddButCannot" />
    </Endpoints>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Comment: You don't have to have an InternalEndpoint dedicated to each interface. Think of an "InternalEndpoint" as an endpoint for a firewall (i.e. an opened port), not a WCF endpoint. These endpoints are NOT the same as WCF endpoints. For instance, we have ~250 different TCP WCF services hosted on a single InternalEndpoint. Almost think of this InternalEndpoint as mapping to your WCF bindings/behavios rather than to your WCF endpoints.

Comment: Yep, treating Azure endpoints and WCF endpoints as a one-to-one was my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment to your question, I don't think you really need all of those `InternalEndpoints` that you have. You are pairing those one-to-one with your WCF Endpoints. This is probably wrong. Instead, pair them up with your WCF Bindings/Behaviors (i.e. one per port, really). In our case, we have ~250 different WCF Services all going through this one endpoint. Here is 100% of our endpoints from our `csdef` file:

```
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="WcfConnections" protocol="tcp" port="8080" localPort="8080" />
</Endpoints>
```

(While we use `InputEndpoint` instead of `InternalEndpoint`, there should be no difference from this question's perspective.)

That single endpoint is utilized by three different `netTcpBindings` in our Self-Hosted TCP service application. We also have a Web App version of our TCP services (for easy local dev hosting/testing in IIS) and the bindings we use are:

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="A" maxBufferPoolSize="5242880" maxBufferSize="5242880" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880" listenBacklog="100" maxConnections="1000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="256" maxStringContentLength="16384" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="B" maxBufferPoolSize="15728640" maxBufferSize="15728640" maxReceivedMessageSize="15728640" listenBacklog="100" maxConnections="1000">
      <!-- 15MB max size -->
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="256" maxStringContentLength="15728640" maxArrayLength="15728640" maxBytesPerRead="204800" maxNameTableCharCount="15728640" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="C" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288" listenBacklog="100" maxConnections="1000">
      <!-- 0.5MB max size -->
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="256" maxStringContentLength="524288" maxArrayLength="524288" maxBytesPerRead="204800" maxNameTableCharCount="524288" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

In the end, as long as you're willing to share multiple services per port (except for some **very** high-load situations, this should be fine with a proper self-hosting app), then what you're doing is unnecessary.

Perhaps your larger problem and the question you need to learn to ask is, "How can I host multiple services on a single port in a self-hosted WCF app?" If that's the case, check out this code (note, the `endpoint` object we use in the loop is simply a struct that holds a few key pieces of each WCF endpoint):

```
// Build up Services
var hosts = new List<ServiceHost>();
foreach (var endpoint in endpoints)
{
    var host = new ServiceHost(endpoint.ServiceType, new Uri(string.Format("net.tcp://{0}:{1}", FullyQualifiedHostName, SharedTcpPortNumber)));
    hosts.Add(host);
    foreach (var behavior in MyBehaviorSettings)
    {
        if (behavior is ServiceDebugBehavior)
            host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>().IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = (behavior as ServiceDebugBehavior).IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults;
        else
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
    }

    if (endpoint.ServiceContract == null)
        throw new Exception();
    if (endpoint.ServiceBinding == null)
        throw new Exception();
    if (endpoint.EndpointUrl == null)
        throw new Exception();
    if (endpoint.ListenUrl == null)
        throw new Exception();

    // Add the endpoint for MyService 
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(endpoint.ServiceContract, endpoint.ServiceBinding, endpoint.EndpointUrl, new Uri(endpoint.ListenUrl));
    host.Open();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this mean that all of the contracts must be implemented by the same implementation class (endpoint.ServiceType in this case)? I'm hoping to keep my implementations separated, too.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming that to get multiple contracts on the same endpoint, the call to AddServiceEndpoint would be in a nested loop, like:

`foreach (var endpoint in endpoints)
{
    var host = new ServiceHost(endpoint.ServiceType, uri);
    foreach (var contract in endpoint.ServiceContracts)
    {
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(contract, endpoint.ServiceBinging, endpoint.EndpointUrl, new Uri(endpoint.ListenUrl));
    }
}`

Comment: The code I gave you runs in production for us. It's not just an example. They don't need to implement the same interface at all. In my code, `serviceContract` is the interface that's implemented and is different for each service.

Comment: your comment on my question turned out to be the key: I have indeed been falsely equating Azure endpoints and WCF endpoints, and my code was enforcing that misconception. Now that I've made that a one-to-many instead of one-to-one, I'm able to successfully reduce my Azure endpoints drastically. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well I would say that you pushed the SOA "principles" a bit too far, if the end result is something like 25 services. Document service?! ILoggingService?!

There are a few good services that should not really exist as individual entities, because they are something that supports your system but they are not services per se. I would say that you need to changes a few of your services, combine then something like 10 would even be a very big number.

Something like this:

- Support

  - Logging
  - Document
  - Localization
- Articles
- Products
- Customers

  - Authentication
  - Authorization

Something like that, with 4 services only. I think you're missing the composition aspect.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you got distracted by the made-up example service names I used. We're comfortable that our service granularity is correct and again, "We really don't want to arbitrarily start combining service contracts". I'm asking if there's a way around the limit of 25 WCF services.

Answer (score 0):

WCF can host several services on same physycal port.

For example if you register your services to endpoints like:

http:// 145.12.12.23:1000/

Then you will not be able to use same port.

But if you will add to the end for example contract name - you able to register services to such endpoints:

http:// 145.12.12.23:1000/AContract

http:// 145.12.12.23:1000/BContract

http:// 145.12.12.23:1000/CContract

WCF will create proxy that will map each URL to specific host.